# Custom Output directory for a .NET Web Project

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Whenever I choose a custom output folder in a WCF Service or Web project in VS .NET 2008, running the project always gives me errors or inconsistencies as far as finding the right referenced assemblies.

For example, if the output folder is < solution root >\bin instead of < solution root >\Project\bin, the project will still attempt to find assemblies in "< solution root >\Project\bin"). Is there no way to specify arbitrary dll output for web projects and have them run correctly?

-Tim

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your include paths as well, right?  Maybe under "Reference Paths"?

Comment: Hm, but this happens even for projects in the solution - and not only that but how would you change the referenced paths so they would be valid both in the dev environment and at runtime (from a different place)? Shouldn't it be fine that they're in the output folder?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: don't sail against the wind. Don't use custom output paths for web projects, as ASP.NET needs to know where the output is at.